# Use GitHub API to create an 'internal' organization repository

Tags: github

As the title states, I would like to create an internal repository within an organization in GitHub Enterprise, how can I do that?

The following code works fine and will create a private repo, but I can't find the setting or flag to create an internal repository. Searched the web and Stack Overflow but I found nothing specific for an internal repository.

```
curl --location \
  --request POST 'https://api.github.com/orgs/my_personal_org/repos' \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic ***** Secret Token ****' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-raw '{
    "name": "new_repo_demo_001",
    "private": true,
    "description": "Test create repo with API"
  }'
```

Answer (score 1):

The admins found a flag that resolves this issue, the correct api call looks like this, note the "visibility" flag:

```
curl --location \
  --request POST 'https://api.github.com/orgs/my_personal_org/repos' \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic ***** Secret Token ****' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-raw '{
    "name": "new_repo_demo_001",
    "private": true,
    "visibility": "internal",
    "description": "Test create repo with API"
  }'
```

The other issues regarding OAuth scopes are referenced by VonC also control how this works.

My thanks to VonC for helping me understand this process.

Comment: Great, well done! Upvoted.

Comment: I have edited my own answer accordingly.

Comment: Who needs docs, we have Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

A [`gh repo create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create) does have an `--internal` flag, which would be one option to create your own repository.

As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/1935#issuecomment-698224015)

```
export GH_HOST=example.com
gh repo create --internal org/reponame
```

---

But using the [GitHub Repository API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-an-organization-repository), you will see:

> When using [OAuth](https://docs.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/), authorizations must include:
>
> - `public_repo` scope or `repo` scope to create a public repository. Note: For GitHub AE, use `repo` scope to create an internal repository.
> - `repo` scope to create a private repository

So if your token has a `repo` scope, and you do not create a private repository, your repository should be '`internal`'.

It is the equivalent of:

```bash
curl -L \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/repos \
  -d '{"name":"Hello-World","description":"This is your first repository","homepage":"https://github.com","private":false,"has_issues":true,"has_projects":true,"has_wiki":true,"visibility":"internal"}'
```

Again: `"private":false`, *not* `"private":true`.
But also: `"visibility":"internal"`, as [noted by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76230821/6309).

Comment: Thanks for the update, I spoke with our admins and it looks like I will need to find a work around. Sadly the CLI is not an option at this time, so I'm not sure what kind of work around I could even find? I am researching the GraphQL but it's quite complicated, we shall see. Also, nice catch on the OAuth, I looked into that and the service account I am using does not have rights to create public repo's, so even if the API supported some kind of 'internal' option, I couldn't use it. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @vscoder The CLI is just the translation of a `curl` call. If you can make said call, visibility public, but with a OAuth scope 'repo', your repository will be internal. I have edited the answer to illustrate the `curl` call.

Comment: I checked and the service account I am using does have the 'repo' auth in X-OAuth-Scopes but I still get "Public repositories are not permitted for Enterprise Managed Organizations." error. I am pretty sure the admins have restricted the service account, I am meeting with them in a few days.