# Create repository from template GitHub API does not provide the "Internal" visibility option

Tags: python, git, rest, github, repository

I noticed that the [GitHub doc](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-repository-using-a-template) doesn't explain how to create an internal repository from a template, using GitHub APIs.

I've also seen in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76202814/use-github-api-to-create-an-internal-organization-repository/76230821#76230821) that there seems to be a "hidden" flag, called visibility, that allows you to create a repo with that visibility, however, the repo in that case is not created from a template.

I tested it by providing the visibility flag, and as expected, GitHub returns the following error:
"Invalid request.\n\n"visibility" is not a permitted key."

The code is the following:

```py
    url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{template}/generate"

    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/vnd.github+json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {ghp_token}",
        "X-GitHub-Api-Version": "2022-11-28",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    repo_name = f"xyz"

    description = "repo xyz"

    data = json.dumps(
        {"owner": owner, "name": repo_name, "description": description, "include_all_branches": False, "private": True,
         "visibility": "internal"}
    )
```

I also tried changing private to True, but the outcome is the same.